# generics in service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I have a WCF with a method that return a class of generics like this

```
public class Response<TOutputContract> 
{        
    public TOutputContract Output { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

i have a project with Service Reference to that WCF. 
When i try to update the service reference, visual studio create another class without generic.

```
public class ResponseTOutputContract
{        
    public TOutputContract Output { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

How can i generate the same class in the service(with generic)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `[DataContract]` would have to expose the generic:

```
[DataContract]
public class GenericSample<TGeneric>
{
     private TGeneric id;

     [DataMember]
     public TGeneric Id 
     {
          get { return id; }
          set { id = value; }
     }
}
```

Once we've outlined our `DataContract` you would implement your `ServiceContract`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBoundGeneric
{
     [OperationContract]
     GenericSample<int> GetObject(int id);
}
```

This is where you will specify the type, so depending on your implementation will vary on how you structure your `DataContract`.